# how to change table class with a dark mode button

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

i just added a dark mode toggle button from a youtube video the html code for it is

```
<div class="dark-div">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
     <label class="label" for="chk">
            <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
            <div class="ball"></div>
         </label>
     </div>
```

**i wanted to change table class name when the dark mode button gets clicked as i'm using bootstrap class on my table i mainly wanted the class of it to get changed to another bootstrap class (for dark table)**

this is my table in html

```
<table id ="myTable"class="sortable table table-striped table-hover dataframe">
```

**i want the class to get changed to "sortable table table-dark table-hover dataframe"**

the js code for dark mode button

```
<script>
        const chk = document.getElementById('chk');

chk.addEventListener('change', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');


});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're toggling the class on the `body` rather than on your table. In your event listener callback, you will instead need to target the table:

```js
document.getElementById('myTable').classList.toggle('table-dark');
```

Comment: this works but the it adds the table-dark class to it if I'm not wrong but I also want the the "table-stripped" from OG class to get removed cuz it's making the table weird in dark mode so how can I do that too?